# I installed Ubuntu 13.04...but Windows is still on my computer

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows

Whenever I start my computer up I am prompted to choose between Windows and Linux instead of it automatically going to Linux. I guess I screwed up somewhere in the installation process but how can I reverse this so Windows is 100% gone from my life?

Comment: just to add, I installed linux with the wubi installer

Comment: wubi is not supported by Ubuntu anymore.Its better to do a new installation by booting from a cd or usb

Answer (score 1):

Wubi installs Ubuntu on your existing Windows partition. If you wish to totally get rid of windows, you will need to do a fresh installation using the standard installer (not Wubi) and set it to use the entire disk drive.

Answer (score 0):

Using System Tools, Administration, GParted Partition Editor (requires your sudo password), find the NTFS partition for Windows, unmount it and delete it.

Comment: I might as well ask with another question, when I first installed Ubuntu with wubi, I only allocated 18GB of memory just because it was the default option. If I delete Windows, will all the remaining memory be allocated to my Linux distribution or will it go into limbo or what?

Comment: My answer is not relevant when Wubi is involved.But yes, deleting the Windows (NTFS) partition means it goes into limbo as unused space. You can reformat it as an ext3/ext4 partition and mount it as extra space, though..